# Errors in Error List but no red squiggly lines showing

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-2017

Hey all I am creating a **C++ Dll** and it seems that I have **102 errors** when compiling **BUT** none are shown in the code at all! Clicking on an error goes to that line but again, without the **red squiggly line**.

> 1>------ Build started: Project: AES, Configuration: Debug Win32
>
> stdafx.cpp
>
> AES.cpp
>
> error C3646: 'set_key': unknown override specifier
>
> error C2059: syntax error: '('
>
> error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
>
> error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'byte'
>
> error C3646: 'encrypt': unknown override specifier
>
> error C3646: 'cbc_encrypt': unknown override specifier
>
> error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'byte'
>
> error C2535: 'void AES::printArray(void)': member function already defined or declared
>
> syntax error: missing ',' before '['
>
> syntax error: missing ')' before ';'
>
> error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
>
> error C2065: 'arr_pad': undeclared identifier
>
> error C2659: '=': function as left operand
>
> error C2563: mismatch in formal parameter list
>
> error C2568: '<': unable to resolve function overload

And this is what the code looks like:

[image]

I've already tried:

> Deleting the .Vs folder and restarting VS and also un-checking the option
>
> Going to Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced > Disable Squiggles: False
>
> Going to Tools > Import and Export Settings... > Reset all settings

My version:

[image]

Anyone else having this issue? Any fixes?

It looks like the red squiggly lines are on Christmas vacation (National Lampoons-style)

Comment: @drescherjm Those are from the output table. Granted its not all 102 of them.

Comment: It looks like you lost the line number and file information. That is why I thought you were displaying the Errors List instead of the Output Tab.

Comment: *without the red squiggly line.* -- It's gotten to the point where we rely on "red squiggly lines" to write, compile, and diagnose C++ code :(

Comment: @drescherjm I omitted a lot of it so it wouldn't be a turn off with this massive amount of errors posted. The error lines would be unnecessary in this since.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Most of the errors from the list make no sense. Regardless I am unable to compile and run it due to this to even **start debugging** the code.

Comment: I have seen many false positives with Intellisense but not usually not false negatives. I am not sure what is going on here.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I, for one, welcome our new squiggly overlords.

Comment: @SombreroChicken "We've got a mission-critical app to develop -- darn those missing red squigglies are messing up everything."

Comment: Is the coloring for the member functions correct? Why I ask is In my IDE AES::AES() will be all blue not blue::black. To me it seems it is not recognizing the member functions.

Comment: Is your `#include "stdafx.h"` the first line of AES.cpp or do you have #include "AES.h" above that?

Comment: @drescherjm yes sir it is.

Comment: `void AES::printArray(void)': member function already defined or declared` is interesting.

Comment: It could be some fundamental syntax error that IntelliSense can't recover from and gives up. Start with the first error and follow the code "backwards".